# Writing a 12 Factor App with Webpack?

Tags: webpack, systemjs, 12factor

How would you go about writing a 12-factor webpack/expressjs application? In particular, I would like to have some application configuration supplied at runtime by environment variables on the expressjs server.

At the moment, I create a global Config object in `<script>` tags, and populate this through rendering a template and passing in the values but I would like to use webpack externals and wrap this as a proper module. Has anyone tried to do this, or have a similar solution?

Comment: Great question. Also currently trying to work out how to pass env vars to webpacked js; webpack seems to not letting the dynamic vars through

Comment: @OlivUtilo you can pass env variables at build time through `--env.VAR1`, and use them in your code as `process.env.VAR1` as in `const ENV = {VAR1: process.env.VAR1}`

Comment: I was using a create-react-app'd app, and any vars prefixed REACT_APP_ went through magically. Retrieved by doing a `window.env = process.env`, which compiles to assigning a hardcoded object which can be used dynmically throughout the app, similar to your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

However painful it is for me to admit to it, I just `sed` my way into 12-factor compliance from the container's `ENTRYPOINT` script.

[For example](https://github.com/epfl-si/lhd.frontend/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

INJECT_JSON_FILE=/12factor.json   # Mounted from Docker volume or Kubernetes ConfigMap
HTML_FILE=build/index.html

set -e -x

main() {
    source_dir=build
    serve_dir=/tmp/serve
    cp -a "$source_dir" "$serve_dir"

    if [ -f "$INJECT_JSON_FILE" ]; then
        inject_json_file "$INJECT_JSON_FILE" "$HTML_FILE" < build/index.html > /tmp/serve/index.html
    fi

    exec serve -s "$serve_dir"
}

inject_json_file () {
    local json_file="$1" target_html_file="$2"

    sed 's/></>\n</'g < "$target_html_file" | while read line; do
        case "$line" in
            "<"script*)
                echo "<script>window._12factor = "
                cat "$json_file"
                echo ";</script>"
                ;;
        esac
        echo "$line"
    done
}

main
```

Answer (score -1):

One way of using ENV variables with webpack is through `--env.VAR1=var1-sample`.

You can create an `environment.js` file with:

`export ENV = {
  VAR1: process.env.VAR1 || 'local-development'
}`

At build time NODE will replace those values with yours gathered from `--env.VAR1`.